# Combining several columns with numeric values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This should be really simple, but I cannot find a solution that produces an acceptable result. I have the following dataframe:

```
 df = Building  Block   Lot 
       A         5731   54
       B         5738   34
```

Now I need to combine the Block (dtype float64) and Lot (dtype float64) columns, but also preface all combinations with "30" and add "00" directly after Block. The desired result is:

```
df = Building  Block  Lot   BBL
      A        5731   54    3057310054
      B        5738   34    3057380034
```

It seems like whatever solution I try, something goes wrong. The closest I have been able to come is this:

```
 In:  df['BBL'] = "30" + df.Block.map(str) + "00" + df.Lot
Out:  Building  Block  Lot   BBL
      A        5731   54    305731.00054.0
      B        5738   34    305738.00034.0
```

As you can see, it adds the .0 after each column. I tried using:

```
df['BBL'] = df.BBL.replace(to_replace=".0", value='', inplace=True)
```

But it has no effect. The same was true for this function I found on another post:

```
def trim_fraction(text):
if '.0' in text:
    return text[:text.rfind('.0')]
return text
```

I realize there are a lot of posts about this, but none of them seem to work in my specific case. I must be missing something really obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you want first to convert floats to integers and then to strings:

```
In [78]: df['BBL'] = ('30' + df.Block.astype(pd.np.int64).astype(str) + '00' 
                      + df.Lot.astype(pd.np.int64).astype(str)).astype(pd.np.int64)

In [79]: df
Out[79]:
  Building   Block   Lot         BBL
0        A  5731.0  54.0  3057310054
1        B  5738.0  34.0  3057380034

In [80]: df.dtypes
Out[80]:
Building     object
Block       float64
Lot         float64
BBL           int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. Unfortunately, this still returns a string with the decimals. I'm not sure why it is treating the values like this, as there should be no float datatypes there at all.

Comment: @Steven, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: thanks for that, but when I use this I get the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '305731.00054.0'

Comment: I got it now - you have to change your float's first to int's and then to strings

Answer (score 0):

You can keeps numbers :

```
In [6]: 3*10**9+df.Block*10**4+df.Lot
Out[6]: 
0    3057310054
1    3057380034
dtype: int64
```